# What's unclear about this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I'm genuinely struggling to see what is unclear about [this question about snapping the ball](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14886/can-the-center-move-the-football-before-the-snap)? It seems like a perfectly simple, clear and answerable question to me.

Comment: @jamauss I'd particularly appreciate a response from you here as you used an admin vote to close this. Thanks :-)

Comment: Not sure if "unclear what is being asked" is being used as a stand-in for "low effort" but I'm mentioning it here because this isn't the first question that has been closed as unclear or too broad when it could be reasonably considered otherwise. It reminds me of what happened to [this question](http://sports.stackexchange.com/q/13162). It's not a great question by any stretch, but I wasn't sure how it was unclear (maybe hard to follow, at best). [Previous discussion on meta](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/q/622).

Comment: @ᴍᴀsᴛᴇʀᴍɪɴᴅ_ᴇᴅ I had to choose "unclear" because there is no "general reference" close reason on Sports SE. I think the OP should have included minimal effort of his own research and clarify what he understands and what he doesn't from the rule book. That's what "unclear" was used. The question is not "too broad", not "primarily opinion-based", not "duplicate", not general health and medical advice, not exercise and fitness. Actually, Sports SE needs a close reason to request for research effort like any other SE sites.

Comment: @Rathony You couldn't create a custom close reason? "Close -> off-topic because... -> Other" in the form of "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because..." There's no doubt the other close reasons don't fit, but that's not the point (as addressed in the other meta discussion). "Unclear" isn't a stand-in for "low effort," which you feel fits the criteria of the OP's question.

Comment: @Moderators I need approval for the "research request" close reason, which I had put in years ago...if we do need it as requested.

Comment: @Rathony That's great if you hate it, and you have every right to use your votes the way you see fit. If you're not willing to use what's at your disposal, then what's the point about bringing up what isn't at your disposal and requesting it (ie, I don't think the question deserves my custom close reason)?

Comment: @ᴍᴀsᴛᴇʀᴍɪɴᴅ_ᴇᴅ You've got the point. We need research request close reason, please.

Answer (score 1):

I agree. The question was perfectly clear, if one has any awareness of what the words involved mean in that context.

If one doesn't have such awareness, they should seek clarification, or better, explore the context themselves. This would make them more able to handle similar questions or other questions in the same context later, and perhaps even find the answer during their inquiry.

If one does have an awareness, then closing it as *unclear* is dishonest and unhelpful. Either address any misconceptions in the question, or explain the relevant rules or protocols or traditions in an answer, or downvotes and ignore.

Comment: @Rathony Closing may be unhelpful here because we're telling a new user that his/her question doesn't belong here (and inadvertently be unwelcoming, as a result)...rather than trying to guide said user to developing a clearer question (which isn't distinguishable without commentary). That's where clarification (and guidance to this [post](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/q/611)) would really help.

Comment: @ᴍᴀsᴛᴇʀᴍɪɴᴅ_ᴇᴅ I beg to differ. If they are desperate enough to get an answer, they will edit the question. Also, there was a comment asking if it is high school or college (I don't remember exactly). I am a vote to close it first type of user, especially for those who don't even bother to register here. (As I said, sometimes they are just trolls). Closing a question doesn't have to be taken as unwelcoming. They should know how the site works. It could be a good lesson for them if they want to stay here for a meaningful period of time. This answer sounds insulting to a few existing users.

Comment: @Rathony You make a great point (about being desperate about getting an answer)..as some users tend not to come back. Yes, it doesn't have to be taken as unwelcoming, but it can be (in fact, we rolled out a [new help-center on-topic page](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/416) because of this). Most new users (unless if they are familiar with SE...and sometimes if they are not familiar with Sports SE) don't know how the site works, so expecting that from them from the beginning (given they are legitimate users) is much, in my opinion.

Comment: @ᴍᴀsᴛᴇʀᴍɪɴᴅ_ᴇᴅ Average 55 to 60 questions are asked on English Language and Usage. About 80% of them are from one rep or unregistered users and most of them are closed. Some users don't even bother to guide them now. They got sick and tired of guiding new users there. That includes myself. I am maybe prejudiced and biased against unregistered users, but I firmly believe we should not expect anything from them. They should not come to Stack Exchange in the first place. Well, maybe not all of them, but majority of them. Those who like how SE works will stay, majority of them as on ELU will leave